# Excel how to get the minimum difference between a date and all the dates in another column with conditions

Tags: arrays, excel, date, conditional-statements, aggregate

I am attempting to identify if I have made 'wash sales' from buying/selling stock in an excel sheet.

Imagine I have this data (Ticker is located in cell A1)

[image: Example Data]

I need to do the following.

1. Only evaluate the rows with a loss (Gain/Loss column <0)
2. Only evaluate the rows with a matching Ticker
3. For each row that meets the above criteria, calculate the minimum absolute difference between a given row's buy date and all of the other End dates.

I would expect the results to be the following:

[image: example_results]

The first row has a minimum number of days of 59 between its buy date and March 5th. The second row does not share a ticker with any other row so it does not get evaluated. The 3rd row has a positive gain so it does not get evaluated. The 4th row has 9 days between its buy date and the end date in the first row. It has 8 days between its buy date and the 2nd row's end date but the second row  has a different ticker so it is not considered. The last row has 3 days between it's buy date and the first row's end date. However, these dates would need to be swapped when using the function `DateDif` so the earliest is evaluated first.

So far I have this formula (pasted in cell F2)

```
=DATEDIF(B$2,INDEX($C$2:$C$11,AGGREGATE(15,3,(($A$2:$A$11=$A$2)/($A$2:$A$11=$A$2)*ROW($A$2:$A$11))-ROW($A$1), ROWS(E$2:E2))),"D")
```

However, it also considers a row's own end date which it does not need too. I also have to drag it down to get the list of date differences before I can take the minimum. Instead I would like it to only show a single value for the minimum days so I believe it needs some array functionality. I have tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like I was making it too hard by using datedif. Since I didn't have a time component it was much easier to just subtract the dates directly and use array formulas.

This equation worked for me. Note that this is written in google sheets but the only difference is it states ArrayFormula with a () instead of putting the curly brackets around the equation via ctrl+shift+enter.

=min(ArrayFormula(abs($B6-if(D6<0,if($A$1:$A5=$A6,$C$1:$C5,if($A7:$A=$A6,$C7:$C))))))